# How to merge to CSV file line by line

Tags: c#

I'm having two CSV files where the first one looks like this:

```
ID Time PositionX PositionY 
1  23
2  26
3  56
```

And another one that looks like this:

```
ID Time PositionX PositionY
   25   2.5       5.5
   28   4.1       5.6
   35   4.8       6.2 
   66   5.5       7.5
```

The result that I want is:

```
ID Time        PositionX PositionY
1  25(or 23)   2.5       5.5
2  28(or 26)   4.1       5.6
3  35(or 56)   4.8       6.2
```

So basically, I'm trying to merge two different files with different amount of data. But to combine them I need a key, the problem is that the key cannot be exactly the same for both of the data.

So I need to get Line by Line from one data set, see it's time, and see with the other dataset if there's a value close to this. If yes then merge them.

That's why I putted "25(or 23)" because the time is in milliseconds so I need to be sure that the line of the first dataset doesn't match with 28 but 25.

The final Key can be either 23 (from the first dataset) or 25 (from the second dataset). It doesn't matter as long as the line chosen is the closest to the value.

Comment: Well thought. Attempts?

Comment: Add your code to the question and we can help you get it working.

Comment: There's no code for this. I only have logic that is completely out of this subject. 
Just two CSV files to be merged using a key, where this key is not exactly the same. So my first idea is to find the key that is closer to the other (Time) and I don't know how to get first each line of the first dataset and find the calue closer to it in another dataset.

Comment: You know your data, you're the best person to provide a logic for this. For example, 26 in the first dataset is closer to 25 than to 28 in the second.

Comment: Well I made a mistake writing the data so basically it should have been something else. But the idea do you get it ?

Comment: The idea is basically create a data structure for each register (line) of each file, parse both files, putting the data in a List of your created data structure, then do nested loops to find the correponding item according to your logic. Your data structure could be, for example, a class with the properties `int ID`, `int Time`, `double PositionX`, `double PositionY`

Comment: How big are the files.  The easiest way would be to load them both into arrays, and then walk the arrays in parallel (using an index, not foreach) and munge them together.  You probably want some logic for "close enough" on the times, but that's up to you.

Comment: Yes, but the complexity resides in the fact that the values may vary and thus not be the same.

Comment: @Flydog57 Well they can be very big, up to 100'000 lines wich might be awful to process line by line :/

Comment: For example, you could calculate the difference bettwen Time1 and Time2, if it's smaller than a threshold, that's your match! Or for each time in the first file, calculate its difference to each time in the second and choose the one with the smallest difference. That's why I told you that you're the best person to provide a logic, since we don't know your data.

Comment: For big files, the first aproach is better, since you can stop looping when you reach the threashold, but the second one might be more accurate.

Comment: @Magnetron I was thinking as for your second idea. But the thing is that it's going to take to much time to check no ? If I have 100'000 lines for dataset1 and 150'000 lines for dataset2. It's going to be a big O(n*m) complexity wich is awfull.

Comment: Well, there is one way to know... Also, as you find a corresponding item, you can remove it from the list to search, so each loop could be faster than the previously... Or not, as removing itens also add overhead

Comment: Also remember, time is relative. Is one hour a long time? Maybe, if can wait, then no

Comment: Well if it's 1hour than yes time becomes an issue

Comment: That was just an example, you would have to write the code and time it

Comment: If it's a big dataset, then your best bet is likely to find something that can parse CSV line-by-line.  Then open the two input streams and an output stream.  Read a line from each and decide what to do.  For example, if you have files 100 & 150 klines, you need to figure out what to do with the extra lines.  My guess is there's no simple _just use LINQ's Zip method_ solution.  It will be brute force.

Comment: If both files are sorted, then it will be O(n), not O(n*m)

Comment: @Flydog57 i'm going to check for this. I don't really know Linq so it's time to see more about it.

Comment: Are both source files already **sorted** by the time field?  If so, collect all positions that are less than the next ID and **average** them?

Comment: @Flydog57 You are right. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Idle_Mind not a good solution, I mean it doesn't match my needs for the output result.

Comment: ...well, we don't really know your "needs".  =)

Comment: @Idle_Mind You are right I should have said it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out how to do it:

First I get the time of Dataset1:

```
String[] File1Rows = File.ReadAllLines(secondSensor.MyFile);
int number = Convert.ToInt32(File1Rows[1].Split(';')[0]);
```

Then create a list of strings made out of Dataset2:

```
String[] AccelerometerRows = File.ReadAllLines(fifthSensor.MyFile);
List<string> AccelerometterTimes = new List<string>(AccelerometerRows);
```

Then I take only the times in Dataset2 and put them into a list of strings

```
List<int> AccelerometterTimesList = new List<int>();

for (int i = 1; i < AccelerometterTimes.Count; i++)
{
  var x = AccelerometerRows[i].Split(';')[0];
  Console.WriteLine(x);
  AccelerometterTimesList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(x));
}
```

Use a little bit of LinQ to get the closest value with O(n) complexity:

```
int closest = AccelerometterTimesList.Aggregate((x, y) => Math.Abs(x - number) < Math.Abs(y - number) ? x : y);
```

Then print it out:

```
Console.WriteLine("number: "+number);
Console.WriteLine("closest "+closest);
```

After this was found, now we use `closest` to get the line of Dataset2 that we need to get it's position. We take then the position, put them in the line of `number` from Dataset1.